# Is there admin setting available to apply different "Shipping Methods Depending on weight"?

Tags: magento2, orders

I want to implement different Shipping Methods Depending on weight of products in order.

**For ex.** Configure USPS to be used for packages under 2 lbs
Configure Fedex to be used for packages over 2 lbs

Comment: have you checked table rate shipping method?